# Symfony2 :I have got error "spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is code is work fine when I am creating a category, when we create a subcategory it gives error.

In Entity file:

```
  /**
     * Music\Bundles\Core\Entity\MusicCategory
     * @ORM\Table(name="ms_musiccategory")
     * @ORM\Entity()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Music\Bundles\Core\Entity\Repository\CategoryRepository")
    * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"},message="The name is already in this system.")
  */
    class MusicCategory 
   {
/**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MusicCategory")
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_Id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * 
     */
    private $parentid;
```

In Formbuilder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('parentid', 'entity', array('class'=>'MusicCoreBundle:MusicCategory',
            'property'  => 'name',
            'required'  => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');},
            'empty_value' => 'No category'

            ));
}
```

Comment: If I knew the answer, I would post it. But I don't.

Answer (score 2):

Change into Entity file:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

    /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MusicCategory", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    protected $children;

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MusicCategory", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $parent;

    public function __construct()
{
         $this->parentId = null; // Default value for column parent_id
         $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Change into formbuilder also:

```
    ->add('parentid', 'entity', array('class'=>'MusicCoreBundle:MusicCategory',
            'property'  => 'name',
            'required'  => false,
             'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');},//->where('s.parentid is NULL')
            'empty_value' => 'No category',
            ));
```

Use this code.feel free to enjoy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing something like
`$category->setParent($parentId);`

where you should do
`$category->setParent($parent);`

where `$parent` is an object of type 'MusicCategory'
Doctrine works with entities, not id(s)

also take a look at
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

mainly the parts about self-referencing associations.

Comment: thanks for replying but where should i write this code?please help me..:)

Comment: i have added code in controller: `if($parent_id = $form['parentid']->getData()) {
             $category->setParentId($parent_id->getId());
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I think its a association mapping problem...
You should check the association...